# Excel formula, count cells up to the last higher than zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I´m trying to find out a formula in excel which would count cells up to the last cell which contains value higher than zero.

Example row: 0,1,7,0,0,1,3,4,0,0. Here the output should be 8, because 8th cell is the last cell which contains number higher than 0.

Any suggestions or help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=XMATCH(TRUE,A1:A10>0,,-1)`

The `-1` argument makes it lookup from the end to the start.

Comment: Thank you very much P.b. It works perfectly. Hats down to your Excel-lent skills !

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need a formula like as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=COUNT(A1:INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(1,1/(A1:A10>0))))
```

---

Or,

```
=ROWS(A1:INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(1,1/(A1:A10>0))))
```

---

Or,

```
=COUNT(A1:XLOOKUP(1,1/(A1:A10>0),A1:A10,,-1,-1))
```

---

Or,

```
=ROWS(TAKE(A1:A10,MATCH(1,1/(A1:A10>0))))
```

---

- `MATCH(1,1/(A1:A10>0))` it returns the last cell position in the range which is higher than `0`
- `INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(1,1/(A1:A10>0)))` it returns the last cell value in the range which is higher than `0` i.e. `4`
- `A1:INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(1,1/(A1:A10>0)))` creates a range from first cell to the last cell which is higher than `0`
- Wrapping within `COUNT()` or `ROWS()` shall return the total counts which is needed.

Comment: Thank you Mayukh, for your suggestion. I appreciate your help.